# Python - Multiple decorators to a method malfunctioning

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to learn decorators and have overcome a strange condition while having multiple decorators for a method. I have two decorators `@makeupper` and `@decorator_maker_with_arguments`.

`@decorator_maker_with_arguments` demonstrates how the arguments are accessed inside a decorator. This works perfectly fine by printing the supplied args but I see `@makeupper` malfunctioning. It prints `None`. I have put a print statement next to its method definition to see if its called and it printed but never prints the letters in hello() uppercase.

When I comment out `@decorator_maker_with_arguments("swadhikar", "c")` I see the `@makeupper` works good. Can someone explain what I am tangling here?

```
def makeupper(some_fun):    
    def wrapper(arg1, arg2):
        return some_fun(arg1, arg2).upper()
    return wrapper

def decorator_maker_with_arguments(decorator_arg1, decorator_arg2):
    """Decorator make that demonstrates decorators with arguments"""
    print "I am a decorator maker and you passed \"{}:{}\" while calling me...".format(decorator_arg1, decorator_arg2)

    def my_decorator(fn):
        def wrapper(fn_arg1, fn_arg2):
            print "I am the wrapper and I can access the method args \"{}:{}\"".format(fn_arg1, fn_arg2)            
        return wrapper

    return my_decorator

@decorator_maker_with_arguments("swadhikar", "c")
@makeupper
def hello(ar1, ar2):
    return "Hello User!"
```

Result:

```
I am a decorator maker and you passed "swadhikar:c" while calling me...
I am the wrapper and I can access the method args "hello_arg1:another hello arg..."
None
```

Comment: your wrapper function inside 'decorator_maker...' doesn't actually call the decorated function - is that intended ?

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 well - it doesn't actually return anything hence the `None`...

Comment: The code is behaving correctly, it's not clear why you expected that `"Hello User!"` would be printed. After you apply the outer decorator, `fn` (at that point actually the `wrapper` from `makeupper`) isn't getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I see @makeupper malfunctioning. It prints `None`

`makeupper` isn't malfunctioning. The outer decorator `decorator_maker_with_arguments` isn't calling the `wrapper` of `makeupper`.

And then you have a `None` because you're not returning anything from the `wrapper` of `decorator_maker_with_arguments`.

The following modifications to `decorator_maker` reflect the proposed adjustments:

```
def decorator_maker_with_arguments(decorator_arg1, decorator_arg2):
    """Decorator make that demonstrates decorators with arguments"""
    print "I am a decorator maker and you passed \"{}:{}\" while calling me...".format(decorator_arg1, decorator_arg2)
    def my_decorator(fn):
        def wrapper(fn_arg1, fn_arg2):
            out = fn(fn_arg1, fn_arg2)
            print "I am the wrapper and I can access the method args \"{}:{}\"".format(fn_arg1, fn_arg2)
            return out          
        return wrapper
    return my_decorator
```

**Output**:

```
I am a decorator maker and you passed "swadhikar:c" while calling me...
I am the wrapper and I can access the method args "hello_arg1:another hello arg..."
HELLO USER!
```

You could add some syntactic sugar by decorating your wrappers with [`functool.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), but arguably it's necessary, at least if you want to keep things like function names, docstrings, etc.

Comment: I guess you could say that `functool.wraps` is syntactic sugar, but arguably it's necessary, at least if you want to keep things like function names, docstrings, etc.

Comment: @WayneWerner Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add return statement inside my_decorator wrapper function.

Like following:

```
def makeupper(some_fun):    
    def wrapper(arg1, arg2):
        return some_fun(arg1, arg2).upper()
    return wrapper

def decorator_maker_with_arguments(decorator_arg1, decorator_arg2):
    """Decorator make that demonstrates decorators with arguments"""
    print "I am a decorator maker and you passed \"{}:{}\" while calling me...".format(decorator_arg1, decorator_arg2)

    def my_decorator(fn):
        def wrapper(fn_arg1, fn_arg2):
            print "I am the wrapper and I can access the method args \"{}:{}\"".format(fn_arg1, fn_arg2)            
            return fn(fn_arg1, fn_arg2)
        return wrapper

    return my_decorator

@decorator_maker_with_arguments("swadhikar", "c")
@makeupper
def hello(ar1, ar2):
    return "Hello User!"

print hello('arg1', 'arg2')
```

Output:

```
I am a decorator maker and you passed "swadhikar:c" while calling me...
I am the wrapper and I can access the method args "arg1:arg2"
HELLO USER!
```